# Populating IIS User Name via ASP .NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

For our system, we have various Web API calls that are internally handled via .NET MVC. These are generic web calls that are authorized via a token header using an AuthorizeAttribute, which means our IIS logs show an anonymous user. We would like to populate that username if at all possible. I thought that using an IAuthenticationFilter and updating the Principal would do the trick, but the User Name of generated IIS logs is stick blank (anonymous). Example code is below:

```
public class UserAuthenticateAttribute : Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter
{
    public async Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //Uses data from within context.ActionContext to populate user data
        context.Principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("Test User"), null);
    }

    public Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
    public virtual bool AllowMultiple { get { return false; } }
}
```

I'm guessing that the IIS log is generated when the request is sent, before it's picked up by AuthenticateAsync. Is there a way to do this that gets picked up by the IIS logs?

Answer (score 0):

IIS will log the application pool identity instead of the website identity.
[image]
If you disable the “Anonymous authentication” in IIS authentication mode, your users will have to authenticate against the website. Assumed we have enabled the windows authentication, IIS will log the network credentials.
[image]

> ## Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus
>
> sc-win32-status time-taken 2020-06-04 07:27:48
> fe80::a4fe:6d79:f2b8:d031%6 GET / - 8002 `VABQIA969VM\Administrator`
> fe80::a4fe:6d79:f2b8:d031%6 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;

However, the website identity is a different thing, it won’t be recorded in the IIS log.
See this link for more details.
https://serverfault.com/questions/40328/in-iis-7-0-what-is-the-difference-between-the-application-pool-identity-and-the
In order to log the website identity, I suggest you use Asp.Net Core built-in logging mechanism.
https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/core/aspnet-core-logging
https://nblumhardt.com/2016/10/aspnet-core-file-logger/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help  with.

Answer (score 0):

IIS captures the name of the Principal that is set **exactly on AuthenticateRequest** event in a [managed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpapplication.authenticaterequest) module in integrated mode or [native](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/smooth-streaming-client/chttpmodule-onauthenticaterequest-method) IIS module. [OWIN uses a special trick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-middleware-in-the-iis-integrated-pipeline#stage-markers) to "schedule" authentication middleware to run on AuthenticateRequest. It looks like the only way to set cs-username in IIS log is to set the Principal in the app handler (Global.asax), a custom module, or use some middleware that will do it in the proper time. Unfortunately, IAuthenticationFilter is called much later.

Thread.CurrentPrincipal (application identity) is synchronized with HttpContext.Current.User (website identity) right after AuthenticateRequest, see a comment to https://www.hanselman.com/blog/systemthreadingthreadcurrentprincipal-vs-systemwebhttpcontextcurrentuser-or-why-formsauthentication-can-be-subtle, it is not the reason why the username is not logged.